# Add header to an existing file

Tags: c#

How to add text beginning of the existing data in a text file. Basically i need to provide a header before this data in a text file. This header is a dynamic data.

this is my actual text

`The claim against the Defendant is for       a breach of contract in respect of a Parking Charge Notice issued to the vehicle.`

header to add is

```
17383001 followed by space (1983).
```

this is my code

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\ee.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
//sw.WriteLine(comboBox7.Text +comboBox2.Text +textBox6.Text);
sw.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3,-1983}", comboBox7.Text, comboBox2.Text,textBox6.Text, ' ');
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is to recreate the whole file:

```
string header = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3,-1983}", comboBox7.Text, comboBox2.Text,textBox6.Text, ' ');
string[] newLines = new[]{ header }.Concat(File.ReadLines(path)).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines);
```

**Update** "i should have blank or empty space of lenght 1983"

Use the [string constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `new string(' ', 1983)`, so:

```
string header = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}"
                 , comboBox7.Text
                 , comboBox2.Text
                 , textBox6.Text
                 , new string(' ', 1983));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Tim, but the headers are dynamic. I am getting them for   comboBox7.Text, comboBox2.Text,textBox6.Text  and i need to have a filler (1983)

Comment: i should have blank or empty space of lenght 1983

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use [**File.ReadAllText**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [**File.WriteAllText**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string fileText = File.ReadAllText("C:\\file.txt");
fileText = string.Format("{0}{1}.{2}", "17383001", new string(' ', 1983), fileText);
File.WriteAllText("C:\\file.txt", fileText);
```